# responsive grid in chakra ui

Tags: reactjs, chakra-ui

I want to make grid with four columns where every element will have the same width but height according to content inside of it. To understand better you can go to Google Keep where notes have same width and different height.

```
<SimpleGrid columns={[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]} gap={5}>
   <Box>
      <Text as='h5' isTruncated fontWeight='bold' fontSize='large'>
        {note.title}
      </Text>
      <Text>{note.text}</Text>
    </Box>
</SimpleGrid>
```

The problem is that Box components have the same height

Comment: Could you share your sample in `codesandbox`?

Comment: There are probably not good ways to work around with `grid` if you want to use fit content height. Many work around were just hacky and lack of browser support. You better rethink of your structure and use `Flex` instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
columns={{ base: 1, md: 2, lg: 3 }}
```